# MapBox, How to detect someone entering in my area

Tags: php, mapbox

Basically I'm iOS developer but I want know about backend funda with MapBox.

My question is if I create zone *(like an area)* on my map look at below image.

[image]

And any people that entering in my zone then how can i get it ?

Look at right side there are pairs of latitude and longitude of corner of zone.
How can I detect or trigger any action when anybody is entering in my zone?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your backend requirements, you can tackle the problem in various ways.

Here is a possible scenario:

1. **Define the target zone.** You can create a [Polygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon) and store the data in a geojson file (this can be done in [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) or [QGis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/))
2. **Pass the user's location to the backend.** This can be done via the browser or via your mobile app.
3. **Make a Geospatial match on the back-end.** You can use a Javascript-based geospatial package such as [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/). There is a module [turf-inside](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-inside) that detects whether a point is within a polygon. `Turf` is a `commonJS` package, so you can use it in Node. For python you have [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) and [fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona).
4. **Fire an enter/exit event** based on the result of the geospatial match.